# Creating kubernetes HA cluster on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, coreos

I have been following [this](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/high-availability.html) guide to set up kubernetes HA cluster on AWS(CoreOS).
Ideally kubelet should bring up api-server by reading the contents of  /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml

but

> api-service is not up, I trace using journalctl, it says cannot start
>   container mkdir /etc/ssl: read-only file system

**The error is very much readable and understandable but how to resolve it ?**

Answer (score 0):

CoreOS has a read-only file system for a lot of critical parts of the OS.

The way to solve it? Write to a non-read only part of the file system:
/etc/kubernetes is read-write so you can put your SSL certs in `/etc/kubernetes/ssl/` for example and point to that location when looking up the certs.